# What is the linear combination of $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a problem where I am finding $A^n$B where B=$[3,1,1]^t$.

I know the steps in solving, but I do not remember how to find linear combination.

I do not see it. There has to be a way to calculate it, but I do not remember.

I have the eigenvectors as $x_1$=$[1,0,-1]^t$, $x_2=[1,-1,0]^t$, and $x_3=[1,1,1]^t$.

For $x_1$ and $x_2$, $λ=0$.
For $x_3$, $λ=3$.

The linear combination being: B= $ax_1$ + $bx_2$ + $cx_3$, and

$$A= \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 \\1 & 1 & 1 \\1 & 1 & 1 \\\end{bmatrix}$$
but it shouldn't be needed because I am not asking for the solution to A$^n$B.

Comment: Your question is highly ambiguous. What is $A$ ? I presume you mean eigen vectors of $A$

Comment: Do you also have the eigenvalues of $A$?